# Displaying images from fetch API call Node/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Im trying display images im fetching from API
btw `url` is defined

```
fetch(url).then((res) => {
            res.blob()
            .then((img) => {
                console.log(img)
                const  objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(img);
                const url = objectURL.replace(/[blob:]{5}/gi,'')
                ReactDOM.render(<Gallery photos={url} />, document.getElementById('root'));
     });
})
```

Gallery.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Gallery extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Images: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({images: this.props.photos});
  }
  render() {
    const {image} = this.props.photos;
    return (
      <div >
          <img 
              className="App"
              width="300"
              height="300"
              src={image} 
              alt="dogs"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```

with or without the regex `/[blob:]{5}/gi` it is only displaying the `alt` prop and not the image. The image is received and the get call is successful but the `objectURL` url is not working. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const {image} = this.props.photos;` is equivalent to

```
const image = this.props.photos.image;
```

It means, *"assign the property `image` of `this.props.photos` to the variable `image`"*.

However, `this.props.photos` is a **string**. Strings don't have a `image` property. You simply want

```
const image = this.props.photos;
```

---

You are not doing anything with `this.state.Images`, so you can remove the constructor and `componentDidMount`.

---

`/[blob:]{5}/gi` doesn't do what you want it to do. It means *"match all sequences of 5 characters that consist of `b`, `l`, `o` or `:`"*

I.e. the character sequence `bb:ol` would match.

If you wanted to remove the sequence `blob:` *at the beginning of the string*, then you should be using `/^blob:/i` instead.

However, you *shouldn't* remove `blob:` from the URL.

---

Complete and simplified example

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function Gallery(props) {
  return (
    <div >
      <img 
        className="App"
        width="300"
        height="300"
        src={props.image} 
        alt="dogs"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(img => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Gallery image={URL.createObjectURL(img)} />,
      document.getElementById('root'),
    );
  })
```

Comment: You are right! Do you know how the `src` prop on `img` translates `blob:`?

Comment: No, but it tells the element that the image data is contained in the string itself, and that the value shouldn't be interpreted as a URL.